# Connecting a calendar view of a list to Outlook

Tags: custom-list, sharepoint-calendar, outlook, overlay

I have a couple of calendar views from a custom list that are overlaid onto a separate master calendar and I am trying to connect them all to Outlook. When I connected the master calendar, none of the overlaid events appeared (which makes sense).

However, SharePoint Online is not giving me the option to connect the calendar view of my list. Is there a way to connect a calendar view of a custom list to Outlook?